# Action parameters showing up in querystring instead of URL

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, routes

I'm doing this:

```
@Url.Action("Details", "MyController", new { id = this.Model.ID })
```

The URLcomes out like this: /MyController/Details?id=1

How do I get it to format the URL like this: /MyController/Details/1

The routes look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{Controller}/{Action}", new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Default-ID", "{Controller}/{Action}/{ID}");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order of routes matters - both urls are valid, and in this case the system gets to the query string one first when looking for a url matching that action.

There's also a possibility you have a case sensitivity issue with {ID} - not sure about that one, but generally it is best to use case consistently.

Comment: Thanks - the ordering was an oversight, oops! It works now with the proper order but the case apparently doesn't matter. I'll still use the same case in the route as I do elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I was having the same problem and I couldn't find the reason.